# How to Optimize Animation.Sample

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to optimize the animation. As I see in profiler, about 20% of my CPU used for 'Animation.Sample'. Is there any way to reduce the sampling accuracy to gain performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to write your own animation system for Unity, which would be probably slower due to Unity's optimizations. You can't do anything about it except tweaking the animation yourself.

- Use fewer bones
- Remove redundant curves
- Ensure that any bones that have colliders attached also have rigidbodies.

Comment: Thanks.I optimize animation.sample by this way below.There are 100 units in the scene, I play 50 units' animations in the odd number frame, and play the other 50 units' animations in the even number frame.